# What's the name of the line where the fingers emerge from?

Tags: word-request

I'm looking for a term for the line where the fingers emerge from (I highlighted this place with a yellow colour). What is this called?

[image: hat]

Comment: A quick google of other similar diagrams lists "palmar digital crease" for that area.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Katy in the comment, I found the answer:  **palmar digital crease**.

> "Digital creases. Usually there are two creases at the level of each
>   joint, being most prory, inent the proximal one. The **palmar digital
>   crease** of the triphalangeal fingers is usually located at the proximal
>   third of the proximal phalanx. The **palmar digital crease** of the thumb
>   is longitudinally oriented and slightly proximal to the
>   metacarpo-phalangeal joint." ([skin creases](https://www.ifssh.info/TerminologyPdfs/Chapter-5.pdf))
>   [image]